# How to set dx-datagrid angular pagination top and bottom of the grid

Tags: angular

```
<dx-data-grid #1 id="1" [dataSource]="APIService">

    <dxi-column dataField="Name"></dxi-column>

    <dxo-paging [pageSize]="pageSize"></dxo-paging>

</dx-data-grid>
```

this codes shows pagination on bottom , how can i show pagination on both side top and bottom in dx-data-grid

expecting to show pagination on both side (top and bottom) to the dx-datagrid

Comment: its not there in the documentation, please raise a feature request on their website!